# How to count number of folders with a specific name and delete oldest

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I require a batch file that will count folders with a certain name and if there are multiple, the oldest should be deleted. Folders are named:

```
"01. Daily Backup 20190219", 
"01. Daily Backup 20190218" and 
"01. Weekly Backup 20190210".
```

Of these, I only need the `"01. Daily Backup 20190218"` folder to be deleted.

Counting all folders is fairly easy via:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad %folder%^|find /c /v "" ') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
```

I am unable to add counting conditions based upon the folder names, for instance "01. Daily*" nor delete the olders. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: ok, you could order by date? `/od` the problem is, you are not showing the full structure, or an example of it, what are the scenraios and other folders in the dir that we cannot touch? do they all have `01` in the beginning? etc.

Comment: So you actually don't need to know the number of matching folders, you just want to have the latest one left, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a scenario using folders that starts with `01. Daily Backup*` only, seeing that is the only example you gave.

```
@echo off
set "folder=01. Daily Backup*"

 for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad /o-d "%folder%"') do set "todel=%%i"
 for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad "%folder%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set "count=%%a"
 if %count% gtr 1 echo rmdir /S "%todel%"
```

So we will `dir` all folders, order by date (newest first) set only the last folder as a variable. then if the counter is more than one, delete the folder which was set as a variable.

*Note*, this does not perform the actual delete yet, it will simply echo it, to perform the rmdir command, remove `echo` from the last line.

**Edit**
Seeing as you want to simply keep the latest folder and delete the rest, simply do this (again, remove `@echo` from the line to perform the actual task):

```
@for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad /o-d "01. Daily Backup*"') do (
  @echo @rmdir /s "%%i"
)
```

Comment: @MaartenVanDerMeijde so does it solve your actual issue?

Comment: Yes, this does solve my issue. I have made one initial adjustment. I think the set "folder=01. Daily Backup*" should be set folder="01. Daily Backup*" 

In order to ensure only the newest folder remains, I have adjusted the script a bit further. Once again, many thanks for your help!

Comment: @MaartenVanDerMeijde, change it back, it was supposed to be like that, but change `%folder%` to `"%folder%"`, _to fix the typo_. Also if a solution solves your issue, you should mark it as accepted, if there are several working solutions, you should select your preferred and mark it as accepted, _(by clicking on the large check mark to its left)_.

Comment: @Gerhard something's wrong. `count` and `todel` are both the same (number).

Comment: @Stephan you are right, that is what you get when you don't test solutions :) thanks. Will fix now.

Comment: @MaartenVanDerMeijde please note the changes made, after issue noticed by Stephan.

Comment: better `:)`  Although I'd do `for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d "01. Daily Backup*"') do rd /s /q "%%a"` to delete them all except the newest one (not quite sure, if that's Maarten's intention).

Comment: @Stephan, yes, that was my idea as well, but I was thinking perhaps he will have 2 pairs of various directories and then loop through a list, only deleting oldest each time, but he did not specify... The count part is what throws me off mostly into catch 22 with that one :)

Comment: @Gerhard: the counting might just be an idea to solve the problem ([X-Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) (Just a note: To keep the last two, just `skip=2` etc.)

Comment: @Gerhard, indeed, you are right. The idea is to keep the newest and delete all the oldest. I managed to solve this to split the code. Maybe not the most effective way, but it seems to do the trick. I will post the adjusted code below ...

Comment: ok, but then we can better the code, no need to return each time. So you simply want to keep the latest folder?

Comment: @MaartenVanDerMeijde see edit bottom of the answer for a shorter version of what you did in your answer.

Comment: @Stephan so it was indeed an X-Y problem `:)` as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
REM Location of Reliplan folders and files
set "dir=c:\temp\"
set "name=01. Daily Backup*"
:start
 for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad /o-d "%dir%%name%"') do set "todel=%%i"
 for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad "%dir%%name%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set "count=%%a"
if %count% gtr 1 goto del
goto further
:del
rd /s /q "%dir%%todel%"
goto start
:further
if "%name%"=="01. Daily Backup*" (
   set "name=01. Weekly Backup*"
   goto start
)
if "%name%"=="01. Weekly Backup*" (
   goto end
)
```

:end

Comment: please read my comments to Gerhard's answer. Better to read and to maintain and easy to adapt to "keep the last [n]"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.